# Bitrix многосайтовость (Symlinks)

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
Хочу узнать сталкивался ли кто то с созданием symlink на BitrixVM ?
Дело в том что у нас многосайтовость, и мы вынесли папки bitrix, local, update, и на каждом сайте сделали симлинки. Все сделано по уроку https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=103&LESSON_ID=287
Но, у нас пропали все сайты из списка в Configure pool sites.
Сами сайты все же доступны(композиты), но не видят ядро.
Что мы могли сделать не так?

Comment: может есть какая-то информация в логах веб-сервера? (nginx, apache) можно попробовать проверить доступны ли shared папки - sudo -u www-data ls -la /var/www/site{1,2}/bitrix

Comment: @Сергей Гамов смотрели логи, но ничего нужного не обнаружили